# Preprocess data using xml to High Chart

Tags: xml, highcharts

I had meet some problem on process xml file to the highchart.

This is my XML file structure.

```
<root>
<Chart>
  <MTH>01</MTH>
  <SUM_CA_>6.78</SUM_CA_>
</Chart>
<Chart>
  <MTH>02</MTH>
  <SUM_CA_>6.78</SUM_CA_>
</Chart>
<Chart>
  <MTH>03</MTH>
  <SUM_CA_>6.84</SUM_CA_>
</Chart>
```

The code to generate the high chart

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var options = {
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Collective Assessment'
            },
            xAxis: {
                title:{
                    text:'Month'
                },
                categories: []
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Persentage of Default'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },
            series: []
        };


        $.get('MonthlyCollectiveAssessment.xml', function(xml) {

            // Split the lines
            var $xml = $(xml);

            // push categories
            $xml.find('Chart').each(function() {
                options.xAxis.categories.push($(Chart).find('MTH').text());
            });

            // push series
            $xml.find('Chart').each(function() {
                var seriesOptions = {
                    data: $(Chart).find('SUM_CA_').text()
                };

                // add it to the options
                options.series.push(seriesOptions);
            });
            var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        });
    });
```

Result should be push the sum_ca to series and MTH to be the x-axis.
But i dunno why the chart don't display it. Please do a favor for me. I was stuck here long time already..

Comment: In data you should have an array of points, also if is single. Second clue is that point require to be number not string. Try to use something like: data: [ parseFloat($(Chart).find('SUM_CA_').text())]

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But now i had another question on the xml file location. Is that xml file should put at same folder of jsp? Because i think i am not able to read the xml file now..

Comment: It is not required, it needs to be where exists, so take care about correct url / reference.

Comment: Thanks bro! I manage to display the chart already!